# Running opera as a different user in linux

Tags: linux, user-accounts, sudo, opera

I am trying to run multiple opera instances as different users simultaneously in linux mint. I have done it with firefox in the past using the [sux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/sux.1.html) command like `sux user1 firefox`

But if i try that with opera (`sux user1 opera`), nothing happens, it doesn't show any errors and opera wont open. `ps aux | grep opera` shows nothing.

I tried full paths, and `sudo user1` and then`xhost localhost; opera` (which also works with firefox), and `sudo -u user1 opera` but had the same results.

How can i run opera as a different user in linux?

**EDIT:**

Just found that if i create the user using the linux mint "User Accounts" GUI, then it works fine. What could be different from using `adduser` command?

Comment: Works for me using `kdesu` (part of the KDE framework) and I seem to recall `gksu` exists for Gnome - maybe you can try those (or another alternative to `sux`)?

Comment: Tried gksu yesterday and got the same results, command just returns to the shell without any error or message, and opera doesn't open. If I add "-h" it does show the help message, so it seems the command runs but it fails to start silently, and I didn't see any verbosity option to change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Opera portable version ; started from different Directories.

Comment: Still wont open as different user, which i need to later use iptables -m owner module to send each browser to a different interface. I know I can use pid but pids change and the user wont.